# Delphi combobox csOwnerDrawFixed set text property

Tags: delphi

I am using the `csOwnerDrawFixed` style to incorporate my style into a `TCombobox`.  The problem is that I can no longer use the Text Property. I suppose it is read only.  Is there a way to enable the text property?

Comment: Maybe you can achieve your goal using something like `MyCombo.Items[MyCombo.ItemIndex]`.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. What you are observing is a simple reflection of the underlying Win32 control's behaviour.

When you select the `csOwnerDrawFixed` style that is mapped to the combo box `CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` style. And when a combo box has that style, then `WM_SETTEXT` always fails with `CB_ERR`, and `WM_GETTEXT` always returns an empty string.

The reason for this is that when you use the `csOwnerDrawFixed` style then the combo box does not have an associated edit control. Therefore there is nowhere for it to store window text. You only get an associated edit control if the combo box style is `csDropDown` or `csSimple`.